# Webbrick/Mongrel vs Passenger + Nginx for development?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Here is my case:

For production I use Heroku.

The question is what should i use for development:

My alternatives are:

1. Built in Webbrick (or Mongrel)
2. Passenger with Nginx

The question Im asking myself is:

Why would I use the second alternative when I will upload my application to Heroku anyway. Isnt it better to just use Webbrick/Mongrel instead then for development?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common use case for Nginx or Apache in development, is when the project makes use of specific features in either server. Since you're deploying on Heroku, there is as far as I know no way of configuring the server setup.

So I can't think of a reason why you should use Nginx while developing.

Answer (score 2):

I deploy to Heroku a lot and use either Webrick or Thin. No real point in setting up a more complex environment.